# Remove specific divs when specific input is activated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pug

I have set up two inputs buttons (I am using jade ftm...):

```
input(type="image" name="tick" src="tick.png"  onclick="exampleFunction(); return false;" width="50" height="50") 
input(type="image" name="cross" src="cross.png"  onclick="exampleFunction(); return false;" width="50" height="50")
```

Those two input buttons are the children of a div. Each of these divs are rendered when I receive information from the client side and all of them have the same class. So basically I have got two input buttons on each generated div and they are all equal but associated to different divs. Just to clarify:

```
#content_div
            - each x in locals.xxx   //jade syntax//
             .example_class
               input(type="image" name="tick" src="tick.png"  onclick="exampleFunction(); return false;" width="50" height="50")
               input(type="image" name="cross" src="cross.png"  onclick="exampleFunction(); return false;" width="50" height="50")
```

What I want is to be able to **add** or **remove** the parent div of the specific inputs when the input is *tick* or *cross* respectively. Only the specific parent div of where those specific inputs are. I have tried quite a lot but couldn't get it done. I gladly accept jquery if needed. Thanks

Comment: When you say you want to "remove" the parent of the image that was clicked, do you mean to remove the parent and all its children (including the input images)? And how do you click "tick" to add the parent if it (and the "tick" image) weren't there already?

Comment: @BrianStephens I want to remove the specific ".example_class" div of the inputs I clicked. I just refresh the page for now. I will implement sockets later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have tagged `jquery` in the question, I'll share with you a simple snippet using jQuery, hope it get you going.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ALWRRP

For jquery click event listener, 
you can have access to the event object, and event.target is the element that triggered the event. To locate the parent element with `example_class` in the class, you can use `$(element).parent('.example_class')`.

Hope it helps :)